# Задать приоритет выполнения операциям в node.js

Tags: node.js

Для некоторых сервисов для онлайн игры использую node.js. А он, как известно, однопоточный. Из-за этого возникают некоторые проблемы.

Есть часть операций, которые нужно выполнить друг за другом. Конкретный пример - регистрация.

Что-то типо:

```
const promise = pool.run_promise(getCurId);
promise.then(function (result) {

})
.then(function (password) {

})
[...Куча других then...]
.catch(function (err) {


});
```

Нужно сделать запись в несколько таблиц. Суть в том, что эти операции асинхронны. Между выполнениями различных `then` могут вклиниться другие операции от других запросов. Да, когда-нибудь потом управление вернётся к текущему промису и всё продолжится. Но из-за этого, при большой нагрузке, люди иногда ждут регистрации по 40 секунд. Транзакции и т.п. не предлагать, база данных NoSQL, транзакций там нет. Поменять базу тоже не советовать.

Можно ли как-то задать в node.js, чтобы он принудительно весь промис (или серию колбеков) выполнил и не переключался на выполнение других запросов?

Comment: Разнести разные задачи по разным процессам думали? Выделяйте отдельный сервис под регистрацию и будет вам счастье.

Comment: А не проще найти кто занимает в это время процессор и исправить тот код?

Comment: @PavelMayorov эм, я знаю кто - другие асинхронные операции.

Comment: @Suvitruf в таком случае, вам просто не хватает CPU. Приоритет ничего не изменит - просто перестанет работать что-то еще.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev этот запрос был как пример. Таких запросов, которые должны выполнять подряд как транзакция, много. Под каждый отдельный сервис не напишешь.

Comment: @PavelMayorov проблема не в CPU, а в том, что порядка выполнения нет, так как всё асинхронно.

Comment: @Suvitruf а в чем разница?

Comment: @Suvitruf допустим, было бы все синхронно. Что бы от этого поменялось? Вам точно так же было бы нужно сделать дофига запросов подряд.

Comment: @PavelMayorov запросы бы выполнились по порядку за пару секунд.

Comment: @Suvitruf а что им сейчас мешает?

Comment: Они сейчас у вас точно так же выполняются по порядку. За 40 секунд.

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет.

Comment: Что - нет? Поясните, как именно они у вас выполняются и в чем проблема.

Comment: @Suvitruf, "_Таких запросов, которые должны выполнять подряд как транзакция, много._" при асинхронном исполнении нет понятия "подряд" для изолированных "частей" процесса. Если у вас есть **процесс** (юзер-стори, последовательность действий, ...), которому не хватает приоритета - выделяйте его в отдельный сервис и масштабируйте на уровне количества инстансов. Другой вариант -- выделяйте **то, что тормозит** в отдельный процесс и масштабируйте его. Ни один вариант не подошел -- у вас проблема с архитектурой приложения. Возможно вам не нужен node.js, а нужно что-то синхронное.

Answer (score 1):

Ключевая фраза в вашем вопросе "ждут регистрации по 40 секунд". Попробуйте разобраться почему. У вас явно архитектурные проблемы. Попробуйте почитать статьи о том, как работает Event Loop в ноде.

Отвечая на главный вопрос, нет, так сделать нельзя. Коротко говоря, все операции в ноде встают в очередь, и этих очередей несколько - сначала очередь таймеров, потом IO операции, потом основной js и т.д.